# Does $A$ spans $B$ mean the same thing as $\text{span}(A) = B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think that $A$ spans $B$ means that any vector in $B$ is a linear combination of the vectors in $A$, and $\text{span}(A) = B$ means that the set of all linear combinations of vectors in $A$ is the identical to vector space $B$. So these two definitions would be different, right?
For example, if
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 \\1 \end{bmatrix} 
$$
and
$$ 
B = \begin{bmatrix}a \\0 \end{bmatrix}, a\in \mathbb R
$$
then I'm fairly sure that $A$ spans $B$, but span(A) does not equal $B$. since vector space $\text{span}(A)$ has vectors that $B$ does not.
Does $A$ spans $B$ mean the same thing as $\text{span}(A) = B$?

Answer (score 1):

There may be some variation in usage.

For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span says that a set of vectors $S$ spans a subspace $W$ if $W$ is the [unique] subspace spanned by $S$.
This would imply that "$A$ spans $B$" means the same thing as "$\mathrm{span}(A)=B$."

On the other hand, in
[Minimum number of vectors that span a linear subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987354/minimum-number-of-vectors-that-span-a-linear-subspace)
an exercise in a linear algebra course asks for the minimum number of linearly independent vectors that still span $V$, where $V$ is a subspace of some unnamed vector space.
If "$A$ spans $B$" means the same thing as "$\mathrm{span}(A)=B$," then the **only** sets of linearly independent vectors that span $V$ will contain exactly the same number of vectors as $V$ has dimensions, that is, there is no such thing as a "non-minimal" number of linearly independent vectors that span $V.$
That does not seem to be the intent of the exercise: rather, it seems to be assumed that you **need** to say "minimal" in order to exclude sets of vectors that span $V$ and also span a larger subspace.

So I think the answer to the question is context-dependent. The context is how the phrase "$A$ spans $B$" was introduced into the particular mathematical work where you see it.

The usage where the statements have the same meaning (or at least are indistinguishable in effect) seems to be far more common however.
(An example of "indistinguishable in effect" is when you ask if a subset $S$ of vectors in a space $V$ spans $V$. Since the set is a subset of $V$ it cannot span any larger vector space, so either $\mathrm{span}(S)=V$ or $S$ does not span $V.$)